# Internal security checks, how to reach 100 % code coverage?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, exception, code-coverage

I have a lot of classes similar to the following one:

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly Ba _ba;
    
    private Foo(Ba ba)
    {
        if (ba is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(ba);
        
        _ba = ba;
    }
}
```

In other classes' internals, I call this constructor of `Foo`, but as this would be unintended, in each constructor call `ba` is not `null`.

I wrote a lot of test methods for the consisting framework, but I am unable to reach the 100 % of code coverage as the exception in the above code snippet is newer thrown.

I see the following alternatives:

- **Remove the null check:** This would work for the current project implementation, but whenever I might add an accidental call `Foo(null)`, debugging will be more difficult.
- **Decorate the constructor with [`[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.excludefromcodecoverageattribute?view=netstandard-2.0):** This would work for the current `Foo(Ba)` implementation, but whenever I might change the implementation, new code paths in the constructor could develope and accidentally be missed to test.

How would you solve the dilemma?

---

## Notes

The code example is written in C#, but the question might address a general unit testing/exception handling problem.

C# 8 might solve this problem by [introducing non-nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/nullable-reference-types), but I am searching for a good solution until it has been released stable.

Comment: What about having constructor as `protected` and then inherit the class in the test project and run `null` test with this inherited class?

Comment: Simple tradeoff: do you have precedents that you accidentally wrote  `new Foo(null)`? I am pretty sure - none. Then you mentioned that you wrote a lot of tests, that mean that whenever you pass `null` into constructor some test will fail with stack trace pointing to the class which received `null` instead of valid dependency.  Based on above **Remove null check** and enjoy with 100% code coverage and unconditional constructors ;)

Comment: why don't you write a test where you call this constructor and pass null as parameter? Since this is a public class I don't see where the issue is.

Answer (score 2):

You have missed the most important alternative: Don't see it as a desirable goal to achieve 100% code coverage.

The robustness checks in your code are, strictly speaking, not testable in a sensible way.  This will happen in various other parts of your code as well - it often happens in switch statements where all possible cases are explicitly covered and an extra default case is added just to throw an exception or otherwise handle this 'impossible' situation.  Or, think of assertion statements added to the code: Since assertions should never fail, you will strictly speaking never be able to cover the `else` branch that is hidden inside the assertion statement - how do you test that the expression inside the assertion is good to actually detect the problem you want it to?

Removing such robustness code and assertions is not a good idea, because they also protect you from undesired side effects of future changes.  Excluding code from coverage analysis might be acceptable for the examples you have shown, but in most of the cases I have mentioned it would not be a good option.  In the end you will have to make an informed decision (by looking at the coverage report in detail, not only the overall percentage) which statements/branches etc. of your code really need to be covered and which not.

And, as a final note, be aware that a high code coverage is not necessarily an indication that your test suite has a high quality.  Your test suite has a high quality if it will detect the bugs in the code that could likely exist.  You can have a test suite with 100% coverage that will not detect any of the potential bugs.